# R custom function - dplyr selection helpers not behaving as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am writing a custom function to deal with GL string data (see this link if interested in the data format: [GL string](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3715123/))

The data looks like this:

```
(test <- tribble(
  ~case, ~A, ~B, ~DRB1, ~DRB3,
  1, "HLA-A*30:02:01+HLA-A*32:01:01", "HLA-B*15:17:01", "HLA-DRB1*13:02:01+HLA-DRB1*13:03:01", "HLA-DRB3*02:02:01+HLA-DRB3*03:01:01",
  2, "HLA-A*23:01:01+HLA-A*33:03:01", "HLA-B*35:03:01+HLA-B*55:01:01", "HLA-DRB1*08:01:01+HLA-DRB1*11:01:01|HLA-DRB1*08:77+HLA-DRB1*11:277", "HLA-DRB3*02:02:01",
  3, "HLA-A*02:01:01", "HLA-B*50:01:01+HLA-B*51:01:01", "HLA-DRB1*03:01:01+HLA-DRB1*04:05:01", NA,
  4, "HLA-A*02:01:01+HLA-A*32:01:01", NA, "HLA-DRB1*11:04:01+HLA-DRB1*15:02:01", "HLA-DRB3*01:62:01+HLA-DRB3*02:02:01|HLA-DRB3*01:91+HLA-DRB3*02:133"
  ))
```

The function I have written is to separate the strings into two columns. The `|` symbol is the separator. The function also has the option to either keep or discard any extra data after the first `|`. The function I have written is this:

```
GLstring_genotype_ambiguity <- function(.data, columns, keep_ambiguities = TRUE) {
  # Copy GL string to a new ambiguity column
  .data %>% mutate(across({{ columns }}, ~ as.character(.), .names = "{col}_ambiguity")) %>% 
    # Extract the first genotype and put in the original column
    mutate(across({{ columns }}, ~ str_extract(., "[^|]+"))) %>% 
    # Remove the first genotype from the ambiguity column
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ str_replace(., "[^|]+", ""))) %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ str_replace(., "[\\|]+", ""))) %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ na_if(., ""))) %>% 
    # Either keep or remove the ambiguity column
    { if (keep_ambiguities) . else select(., -contains("ambiguity")) }
}
```

This function works as intended when I use `columns` arguments that are natively recognized by `across`:

```
test %>% select(A) %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(A)

test %>% select(DRB3) %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(DRB3, keep_ambiguities = FALSE)

test %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(A:DRB3)

test %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(c(A, B, DRB1))
```

However, it doesn't work when I use selection helpers:

```
test %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(starts_with("D"))

test %>% GLstring_genotype_ambiguity(everything())
```

In those cases, the first ambiguity is correctly extracted, but the remaining ambiguities do not wind up in the columns that end with `_ambiguity`. Clearly, I am misunderstanding something about how the selection helpers work.

Comment: I'm not sure about the full code, but a pointer of where to start could be using `...` to pass the arguments to `dplyr::select()` as in:    `GLstring_genotype_ambiguity_tidy <- function(.data, keep_ambiguities = TRUE, ...) {
  working_cols <- dplyr::select(.data, ...)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are suggesting, but I will point out that the first two lines of the function works fine. Those lines create new columns. The problem begins in the third line `mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ str_replace(., "[^|]+", "")))`. With that line I'm trying to mutate the new columns I just created above. Is there a better way to apply the `mutate` function than selecting them with `across(ends_with("ambiguity")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice by Paul Stafford Allen was to identify the column names within the function and use them concretely. like so

```
GLstring_genotype_ambiguity <- function(.data, columns, keep_ambiguities = TRUE) {
  # Copy GL string to a new ambiguity column
  
  cols2do <- names(select(.data,{{columns}}))
  
  .data %>% 
    mutate(across({{ cols2do }},
                  ~ as.character(.),
                  .names = "{col}_ambiguity")) %>%
    mutate(across({{ cols2do }}, ~ str_extract(., "[^|]+"))) %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ str_replace(., "[^|]+", "")))  %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ str_replace(., "[\\|]+", ""))) %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("ambiguity"), ~ na_if(., "")))  %>%
      { if (keep_ambiguities) . else select(., -contains("ambiguity")) }
  
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can't say as I really understand why, though.